# NSdictionary sorting problem

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I have an array of NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary*  dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:bothUserName forKeys:bothUID];  // here array "bothUserName" and "bothUID" is an NSArray type


[dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

NSLog(@" dictionary objects %@",dictionary);
```

I am getting an output like this.

```
dictionary objects {

 14172368 = webtickle;
271882407 = electrodealio;
314125883 = Coral5mz;
316212228 = ajaysinghHF2;
316348693 = Caroline99a;
43944597 = WorldStuffer;
 }
```

but I want to have output like this.

dictionary objects {

```
 316212228 = ajaysinghHF2;
316348693 = Caroline99a;
314125883 = Coral5mz;
271882407 = electrodealio;
14172368 = webtickle;
43944597 = WorldStuffer;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think interchanging the keys and values may work

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar The mistake there was that I assumed keys in place of values but daveoncode's answer is correct and better when compared to using the block method.

Comment: but your answer is going right. I only modified  return [obj1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:obj2]; instead of string1 and string2 and it is working good. and Yes that answer also seems to ok but unfortunate not working well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**keysSortedByValueUsingSelector** returns a sorted array containing dictionary's keys, you have to use this returned array to retrieve the associated objects:

```
NSDictionary*  dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:bothUserName forKeys:bothUID];  

NSArray *sortedKeys = [dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
  NSLog(@"%@: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Comment: It did not sort perfectly. output is like this.  "Caroline99a","Coral5mz","WorldStuffer","ajaysinghHF2","electrodealio","webtickle".

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar Use `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` instead of `compare:`.